# Server still overload after changing from prefork mpm to event mpm

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, mpm-event

On Ubuntu 14  with  Apache/2.4.7. It is 6 CPU cores with 16GB RAM from Linode.com.

Even after changing to Event MPM it still is overloaded in the same way.

Till noon it was stopping temporarily then I tweaked PHP-FPM with these new values in www.conf:

- Changed max_children from 5 to 40
- Changed max_requests from 500 to 1000

Till night now the sites haven't stopped .

Current `mpm_event.conf`:

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
        StartServers             5
        MinSpareThreads          55
        MaxSpareThreads          150
        ThreadLimit              700
        ThreadsPerChild          320
        MaxRequestWorkers         4800
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

As in the photo, changed to MPM event at 12:00 AM ( it is exactly 24 hours ago and photo taken after noon) but there is no reduction of CPU load:
[image]

Comment: Why do you say this is overloaded? You seem to have plenty of available CPU capacity.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've read that MPM event is much more efficient than prefork but  here I don't see anything like it.

Comment: It is much more efficient. But your CPU usage is coming from PHP, not from Apache.

Comment: @MichaelHampton then should I optimize php-fpm?

Comment: You should optimize your application code. Changing settings in php-fpm will not magically make your code do less than it already does.